# In Excel, how can 1 button control 2 separate functions, where the 1st click hides specific columns and the 2nd click unhides the columns?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I have 2 buttons for each category of contracts.  The information highlighted in pink is what I need to see for each category.  For example, on the LID contracts, when I click the 'Collapse' button, columns D,F,H,I,J,K,L,M,N, P all disappear, showing only whats in pink. Then I have to click the 'Expand' button to reset this.  How can I combine this into 1 button?

Additionally, I have to manually copy/paste the highlighted data in between these 2 functions.

[image]

Comment: Try using column Grouping... You can achieve this without VBA buttons...

Comment: Can't be done on a multiple range selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for column D. Add other columns as needed.

```
With Sheet1 'change as needed to your sheet object name
   .Range("D1").EntireColumn.Hidden = Not .Range("D1").EntireColumn.Hidden
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub toggleHidden()

   ' declare yours columns and sheet
   ' just a sample
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns("G:H")
       .Hidden = Not .Hidden
   End With

 End Sub
```